# why alert is not display while on fiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery

why alert is not display .i check in my safari and chrome browser?I inspect getting this error.

http://jsfiddle.net/LyXLD/1/

```
var lastestCountValue=11;
var file_show_counter=lastestCountValue;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pre").click(function(){
        alert("--")
     //  $('#curr').html('ll');
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Because you have two elements with an id of `#pre`.  An ID should be *unique*.  Change your selector to `$('button#pre')` and it works perfectly.

Comment: the id selector will return the first element with the given id... so it is added to the label with id `#pre` if you click it the alert is coming - the second `naveen` at the top of the page

Comment: **ID of an element must be unique**

Answer (score 3):

you cannot have multiple elements with same id....

```
<label id="pre">naveen</label>
<button id="pre">pre</button>
```

so id "pre" for button is not valid. change this label id to something else and your code would work fine. Currently, click event of label is registered.

```
<label id="prelabel">naveen</label>
<button id="pre">pre</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 elements with the same id of `pre`.  Class names can be duplicated but ids need to be unique.  Try clicking the second "naveen" and it will alert.